# Select row from table but exclude row that has ID already in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have two tables, one table has a list of videos, one has a list of videos that must be from table one, i need to select the rows from the first table that are not present in table two.

Heres table `videos`:

```
VIDEOID    |    videoname
   1             nameone
   2             nametwo
   3             namethree
```

heres table `favs`:

```
VIDEOID    |    videoname
   2             nametwo
```

After the select query, the output should be:

```
VIDEOID    |    videoname
   1              nameone
   3              namethree
```

as can be seen, the video `2` has been omitted, as it is already in table `favs`

I have tried a few seperate SQL queries, but i keep getting syntax errors, I have never done a SQL query that selects data but emits some due to another table, how should this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your friend here is [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html)

```
SELECT videos.* 
FROM videos 
    LEFT JOIN favs ON videos.videoid=favs.videoid
WHERE favs.videoid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ...
FROM videos
WHERE VIDEOID NOT IN (
   SELECT VIDEOID
   FROM favs
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from videos
where videoid not in (select videoid from favs)
```